# Cannot connect docker swarm agent from outside internet

Tags: azure, ubuntu, docker, docker-swarm, azure-container-service

I try to provide Python Flask (port 5000) on Docker swarm by Azure Container Service.

The deployed agent can be connected by `curl 0.0.0.0:5000` from swarm management but cannot connect from outside of internet.

The port 5000 is well defined in agent Azure load balancer. What else can I inspect more?

I launch flask by follwing command.

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 bbb/web /root/startScript.sh
```

The result of `docker ps` is as below. `bbb/web` is what I want to serve.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                                                NAMES
05a96351290c        bbb/web       "/root/startScript.sh"   43 minutes ago      Up 43 minutes       0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp                                                                                                               jovial_meitner
adcc2d45cbe0        swarm:1.1.0         "/swarm manage --repl"   8 months ago        Up 7 weeks          0.0.0.0:2375->2375/tcp                                                                                                               containers_swarm_1
2264e2b1636f        progrium/consul     "/bin/start -server -"   8 months ago        Up 7 weeks          0.0.0.0:8300-8302->8300-8302/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8400->8400/tcp, 53/tcp, 53/udp, 0.0.0.0:8500->8500/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8301-8302->8301-8302/udp   containers_consul_1
```

The result of `docker network ls` is as below

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
66bf169bd8f9        bridge              bridge              local               
2aeb61431acf        host                host                local               
19448e290e2c        none                null                local
```

The result of `docker info` is as below

```
Containers: 5
Running: 3
Paused: 0
Stopped: 2
Images: 3
Server Version: 1.12.2
Storage Driver: aufs
Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
Backing Filesystem: extfs
Dirs: 48
Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
Volume: local
Network: overlay null host bridge
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: apparmor
Kernel Version: 3.19.0-65-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 3.36 GiB
Name: swarm-master-A501B991-0
ID: KKRP:45CG:NSBD:EUP5:PDGV:S3QA:4UUJ:NUIS:YP7I:DBLM:GSXU:47SC
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Username: bbb
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Insecure Registries:
127.0.0.0/8
```

Comment: is there a network security group attached to a subnet? it could be blocking traffic

Comment: @4c74356b41 // thanks for the comment. there's no nsg defined. I have almost identical docker resource group in azure resource perspective, so I think it's the problem of docker or linux setup.

Comment: try recreating the acs environment from scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man, forgive my stupidity.

I missed to make ssh tunnel. It was run on my local machine actually.

```
ssh -L 2375:localhost:2375 -f -N myname@dockertestmgmt.eastasia.cloudapp.azure.com -p 2200
export DOCKER_HOST=:2375
```

Comment: Yes, you need create a ssh tunnel according to this [official article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-connect#connect-to-a-dcos-or-swarm-cluster).

Answer (score 0):

It is probably that you have not opened port 5000 correctly, e.g. missing NSG. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-enable-public-access (that document talks about DC/OS but the process is the same).

Comment: there's no nsg when creating swarm. I found my mistake and post an answer. thanks for your attention